# In-App Purchases test user doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm having issues getting In-App purchases to work.  Every time I create a new test user and debug it on my iPhone after I hit okay with the password I automatically get "You've already purchased this but it hasn't bee downloaded."

I've added this to my viewDidLoad:

```
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

My purchase function looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)purchaseProduct:(id)sender { 
        SKProduct *product = [productArray objectAtIndex:0];  
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
       [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
 }
```

I also have:

```
-(void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

    if ([transaction transactionState] == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased) {
      [self transactionDidComplete:transaction];


    } else if ([transaction transactionState] == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed) {
        [self transactionDidFail:transaction];

    } else if ([transaction transactionState] == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored) {
        [self transactionDidRestore:transaction];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Unhandled case: %@", transaction);

    }
}
```

}

As soon as I hit the purchase button without even entering in my test user account password I receive this error:

```
Unhandled case: <SKPaymentTransaction: 0x25a9a0>
```

Which means, I'm assuming the payment queue is being called before I can enter my password and hit okay to make the purchase!

I do have the code below in the functions "transactionDidComplete, transactiondidFail, transactionDidRestore"

```
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

Comment: Could this be happening because I have ARC enabled?

Comment: Guess not. I added -fno-objc-arc to the files and I still have the same issue.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand how the transaction can fail on a new test user account, when making the purchase for the first time.  Giving the error "You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded."

Comment: Well I found out at least the initial Unhandled case when I pushed the Purchase button was because I didn't implement anything when the transaction state is SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing.

Comment: It may sound dumb, but I created test user accounts under my account instead of my work account because I didn't want to clutter their test user page.  Well now I realized you can't use another developer's test user account on another owner's app. :-/ (SOLVED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing

something like:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
  //NSLog(@"updatedTransactions %@",transactions);
  NSNumber *paymentOk = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
  for(SKPaymentTransaction *t in transactions){
    //transaction failed
    if(t.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed){
      //[self doTransactionFailure:t.error.localizedDescription];
      [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:t];
      continue;
    }
    if(t.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing){
      continue;
    }
    //transaction type here is success or restored
    //extract the app object
    if([t.payment.productIdentifier caseInsensitiveCompare:self.inAppPurchaseIdentifier]== NSOrderedSame){
      NSLog(@"Got payment for %@",t.payment.productIdentifier);
      paymentOk = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:t];
  }
  if([paymentOk boolValue]==YES){
    [self.delegate didPurchaseWithIdentifier:self.inAppPurchaseIdentifier];
  }
  else{
    [self.delegate didFailPurchaseWithIdentifier:self.inAppPurchaseIdentifier andReason:@"Unknown"];
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your method and still even with a new test user. I still get the same results after I enter my password for the initial purchase.   You've already purchased this but it hasn't bee downloaded."